# "The connection was reset" in Firefox only on postbacks

Tags: asp.net, firefox, postback

I'm getting an error message of "The connection was reset" in Firefox on my ASP.NET site. Here are the details:

- doesn't work in Firefox 11, 12, and 14 though appears to 3.6
- happens everywhere on site where there's a postback
- the message comes up in under a second after doing the POST
- works in Chrome and IE
- works locally
- view state is relatively small
- the pages are not performing long operations (e.g., file upload)

I've tried clearing the cache and running Firefox in safe mode, but it makes no difference.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This has to due with Firefox responding to the so-called "BEAST" (Browser Exploit Against SSL/TLS) attack. A workaround is to go to Firefox's about:config and set security.ssl3.rsa_aes_256_sha to false. That doesn't sound a like a good idea to me and I wouldn't ask a client to do that. I'll post back here if I find a better solution. It sounds like something needs to be done at the server level.

Comment: I'm having a similiar issue, it might be related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30998981/post-redirect-throws-a-connection-was-reset-browser-error

Answer (score 0):

Close all of your anti-virus software and restart your FF.

See [solution of connection](http://www.yanfei.info/2011/07/firefox-link-error) was reset for more help.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I can't disable my anti-virus on my work PC. I installed Firefox on a virtual PC and got the same error message there. Assuming my PC's anti-virus isn't interfering with the virtual machine, we can assume that's not the issue.